# Haskell regex syntax

Tags: regex, haskell

I'm having some trouble with regexes in haskell. Specifically:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> "1" =~ "\d" :: Bool
<interactive>:1:10:
    lexical error in string/character literal at character 'd'
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> "1" =~ "\\d" :: Bool
False
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> "1" =~ "\\\\d" :: Bool
False
```

Does Haskell not have the `\d` or `\s` or other such convenient escape codes? Yes, I know I can do `[0-9]` instead, but the escape codes can be so much more convienient for complex regexes. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: It would be great to see an example solution that actully matches `\\d` or some variant of this as I am still struggling

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know much about the Haskell regex packages, but from your examples above with "Text.Regex.Posix", I might infer that you're dealing in POSIX regular expressions. Escape sequences such as \d and \s aren't part of POSIX regex syntax, and I believe originated with Perl and have since propagated into other languages.

Comment: The `Text.Regex.Posix` module uses foreign function bindings to the POSIX regex C API, I believe. So you are very likely correct.

Answer (score 15):

No, the Haskell language does not have escape sequences like `\d` and `\s` or regular expressions in general. There are just some libraries which provide regular expressions.

Therefore, you have to look up whether the regex library you are using supports `\d` and `\s`. And when they do support it, you have to write them as `"\\d"` in a Haskell source file.

When `\d` stems from Perl you might be more successful with `regex-pcre`.